# Can I import an exiting table on mysql and override some existing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mysql table in my host named article, I want to import `article.sql` from the localhost to save the changes that I have created on localhost, how can I import that table without deleting it? There are tables connected to article table that's why as much as possible I'm avoiding to delete it.

Comment: I think the best approach is to import the data into a staging table and then use query logic for the changes to the existing table.

Comment: what kind of query logic sir?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following steps:

1. Open your localhost exported `article.sql` file (a simple text file).
2. Change the `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement to reference a different target table such as **article_temp** in order to not conflict with live, production database table, *article*.
3. Again, change any `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE`, and any other queries to reference a different target table.
4. Run the .sql file on the live server. MySQL allows the [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) command. Be sure to back up original table just in case during this process.
5. Run any one of the three append queries below with either `LEFT JOIN NULL`, `NOT IN`, or `NOT EXISTS` clauses (an often debated question in [database industry](https://www.google.com/#q=not+in+vs+not+exists+vs+left+join&start=) on which is more efficient). The key is to find a comparative/matching value (i.e,. article name). Any one below should work, no need to run all of them (but of course each checks for duplicates!)

SQL Append Queries

```
INSERT INTO article (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM article_temp
LEFT JOIN article.value = article_temp.value
WHERE article.value IS NULL;

INSERT INTO article (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM article_temp    
WHERE article_temp.value NOT IN
         (SELECT value FROM article);

INSERT INTO article (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM article_temp    
WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT value FROM article
          WHERE article.value = article_temp.value);
```

Of course once done with the staging and migration, drop the temp table:

```
DROP TABLE article_temp;
```